# EasyQuery - Add subquery by code

Tags: javascript, easyquery

I am trying to nest my queries with easy query by using javascript.

```
var query = new EQ.core.Query();
// fill in the query
var finalQuery = EQ.client.getQuery();
        finalQuery.addColumn({
          "caption": "Item",
          "sorting": "Ascending",
          "expr": {
            "typeName": "ENTATTR",
            "id": "Items.Id"
          }
        });

        query.setModel(finalQuery.getModel());
        finalQuery.addSimpleCondition({
          attr: "items.Name",
          operator: "InSubQuery",
          value: query.query
        });
```

This result in a query looking like this:

> SELECT DISTINCT Items.Id AS Donor  FROM selectiontool.Items AS
>   Items WHERE
>   (   Items .Name IN
>   (**System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]**))
>      ORDER BY  Items

How do I get this working correctly?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, why don't you contact EasyQuery support on their [web-site](https://korzh.com/easyquery)?

As for the question.
I think the problem occurs because your second query is empty at the moment you are using it in `addSimpleCondition` function.

Additionally, it's better to use `getObject` function instead of accessing `query` property directly.